# Is there an equivalent on Kotlin for Swift init(repeating:count:)

Tags: kotlin

I'm just wondering if there's an equivalent on Kotlin for the Swift initializer `init(repeating:count:)`

For example it's really useful to create arrays of arrays with empty values

```
var arrayOfArray = [[String?]](repeating: [], count: 10)
```

I know that Kotlin has `listOf` but I don't know how the pass an array of empty list on a single line...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`init` constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/-init-.html) (it's available for arrays, lists, sets)

```
// 10x0 Array<Array<String>>
val arrayOfArray = Array(10) { emptyArray<String>() }

// 10x4 List<List<Int>>
val listOfList = List(10) { List(4) { it } }
```

Comment: The latter creates 10 `List`s, each containing these 4 lists: `[0]`, `[0,1]`, `[0,1,2]`, `[0,1,2,3]` right? (edit: corrected 0-based indexes)

Comment: @CodeConfident The first creates 1 array of 10 empty arrays. The latter creates 1 list of 10 lists each [0, 1, 2, 3].

Comment: Ah ha! I mixed up the params. So I could use `List(4) { List(it+1) { it } }` to create `[[0],[0,1],[0,1,2],[0,1,2,3]]`?

Comment: Yep: https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/2mrf90hpn4gcqrb7pjlnvmghnc/ebnjfkmt3bllqraq5tkb64sn17

Comment: @RuckusT-Boom perfect! Thanks!